# PHP, submit form and redirect using header and echo out a success message?

Tags: php, session

I am trying to echo out a div with the message "form submitted successfully" on the next page once a user has submitted a form.

i am trying to do this by using $_GET['success'] but can not seem to get the message to display, can someone please point me in the right direction.

code:

submit_form.php:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['success'] = "<div class='success'>Form Submitted Successfully</div>;
header("Location: index.php?success=$success");
```

index.php:

```
<?php
$_GET['success'] ?>
```

Comment: can you not just echo $_SESSION['success']; ?

Comment: $success variable is undefined. An as above, if you are setting a session var, just use that

Answer (score 2):

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['success'] = "<div class='success'>Form Submitted Successfully</div>;
header("Location: index.php");
```

you are setting the session with text message so all you need to do this is to echo the session variable on index.php page

```
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['success']))
    {
        echo $_SESSION['success'];
    }
  ?>
```

Also put `session_start();` at the beginning of every page.

Comment: this wont echo out anything, the url is saying "index.php?success="

Comment: @user3488706 see my code header("Location: index.php"); I have a changed the header code

Answer (score 0):

As you're already setting a `session` variable, just `echo` that out in your index.php file

```
session_start();    
<?php echo $_SESSION['success']; ?>
```

Comment: When i do that i get this error "
Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs\hewden_spms\supplier_fucntion\index.php on line 323
"

Comment: Are you continuing the session into the index.php file with session_start(); ? see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the value in the variable `$_SESSION['success']` and passing `$success` which is undefined so the the error is thrown

Replace you code with this code:

```
session_start();
$success = "<div class='success'>Form Submitted Successfully</div>"; // use the $success
//encode the URL parameter as : 

$success = urlencode($success);

header("Location: index.php?success=$success");
```

And in index.php just echo success as:

```
 <?php 
    echo isset($_GET['success'])?$_GET['success']:'Error!'; 
  ?>
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: that gives me this error "Notice: Undefined index: success in C:\xampp\htdocs\hewden_spms\supplier_fucntion\index.php on line 323
"

Comment: @user3488706 check my updated answer, there two things here 1)either pass the parameter in the url and print via `$_GET` or 2)store the value in the `$_SESSION['success']` and access the it as `echo $_SESSION['success']` that's it!

Comment: this works, however my url looks like this and its very messy "index.php?success=%3Cdiv+class%3D%27success%27%3EForm+Submitted+Successfully%3C%2Fdiv%3E"

Comment: @user3488706 right the URL will be like this as it is encoded, if you don't the URL to be like this then store message in session as `$_SESSION['success'] = "Form Submitted Successfully"` and don't pass this in the header, you can directly access this in index.php just start the session as `session_start();`  and echo the `$_SESSION['success']`; this will do the job

Comment: @sandip where you have seen this kind of url? It is not the right way

Answer (score 0):

There is not need to use first two line in you first page. Just use redirection as you have used it on your third line and display message on your next page "index.php" like this:

First page:

```
header("Location: index.php?success=done");
```

Index.php page:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['success'])=="done")
{
    echo "<div class='success'>Form Submitted Successfully</div>";
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) in C:\xampp\htdocs\hewden_spms\supplier_fucntion\index.php on line 325

Comment: @user3488706, please try again.

Answer (score 0):

The amount of errors in your code is huge:

submit_form.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['success'] = "<div class='success'>Form Submitted Successfully</div>"; // added " at the end
header("Location: index.php?success"); //Do NOT pass HTML in here. That makes an XSS security vulnerability 
?>
```

index.php:

```
<?php
session_start(); //ALWAYS start with session_start if you use sessions. session_start should be at the very beginning of your page.
if(isset($_GET['success']))
    echo $_SESSION['success']; //you put your data in _SESSION, you echo it from _SESSION
?>
```

Comment: this keeps the success div up even if the user hasnt submitted the form yet tho

Comment: @user3488706 See update. It shows it because it was already in the session. Maybe you should clear the session when it is echo'ed?: unset($_SESSION['success']);

Comment: is the code for index.php correct, i get a syntax error? "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\hewden_spms\supplier_fucntion\index.php on line 326"

Answer (score 0):

It should work 100%.

First page:

```
header("Location: index.php?success=done");
```

Index.php page:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['success'])=="done")
{
    echo "<div class='success'>Form Submitted Successfully</div>";
}
```